# Actionscript Button click to Flv video Help

Tags: flash, actionscript, flv

I'm new at actionscript and not sure how to do this.

I have a button named btnPlay and an flv video named valerie.flv
I would like it when the button is pressed, the flv video plays in the same flash file through the standard flv player.

I tried everything I could and I just have no idea. I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: @BumbleB2na It doesn't matter to me in which, I tried both. Whichever you like most I guess.

Comment: also, is this going to exist on a live web server or will it be in a video played locally?

Comment: It will be on a live web server, but the files will be located in the same directory if that helps.

Comment: Yes, it makes a difference. If deployed on a web server, the flv must sit somewhere within the same domain or else Flash Player requires in security settings that you allow that domain in order to retrieve the flv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS3 solution:

This all takes place on one frame in the timeline.

1. Components Panel > Video > FLV Playback <-- drag this component on to the stage
2. In Component Inspector panel, with flv playback instance selected, set:

   - source:  valerie.flv    (this is a relative html path that will only work if flv in same folder as your html and swfs)
   - autoplay:  false
3. Then, with flv playback instance selected, in Properties panel, set:

   - myVideo as the instance name
4. Components Panel > User Interface > Button  <-- drag on to stage
5. With button instance selected, in Properties panel, set:

   - myButton as the instance name
6. In Component Inspector panel, with button instance selected, set:

   - Label:  Play Video
7. With the frame selected that both these components are on, open Actionscript window and enter this:

   import fl.controls.Button;
   import fl.video.FLVPlayback;

   var playBtn:Button = myButton;
   var flvVideo:FLVPlayback = myVideo;

   playBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClick);

   function buttonClick(e:MouseEvent) {
       var button:Button = Button(e.target);
       button.enabled = false;
       button.label = "Playing...";
       flvVideo.play();
   }
8. Upload your valerie.flv file to the same folder where your html and swf will go.
9. Publish the Flash movie and copy the html and 2 swfs to that folder.

Comment: Wow, that's really in depth. Thank you so much. This helps a lot!

Comment: No problem. I prefer making the button and flv playback instances dynamically in code, but this will get the job done.